# Is it acceptable to store profile pictures publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, authentication, amazon-s3, user-profile

Straight to the point, I store user's profile pictures in an AWS S3 bucket, using the following format: `<company-uuid><user-uuid>.jpg.` This naming convention results in generated URLs that are almost impossible to guess by outsiders.

Example: `https://---.---.com/8794ee24-24ae-49f1-9cff-22d23b0ebef7957a74be-f1ac-493b-b866-b90311bf63a2.png`

Is it acceptable to store these profile pictures (using the naming convention listed above) publicly, or should some type of authentication middleware be used nonetheless?

Comment: Whether it's acceptable or not is entirely dependent on what the users expect of the software.

Comment: Have you considered using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) in your app to grant access to private objects? Basically, when your app wants to show a picture, it can calculate a pre-signed URL to show the picture, but it is otherwise kept private.

Answer (score 1):

I’d strongly recommend erring on the side of caution and restricting public access to any images or content provided by your users. This is especially true if you are not doing any processing on the image to remove metadata; EXIF data could reveal much about who took the image, which could have all sorts of privacy implications.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the removal of metadata, I'll take a look at that for sure

Comment: What is “acceptable” is a bit dependent on what the user expects. Not only that, it depends on other factors too: who are the users? what are the legal requirements where your app and/or users are based? IMO “best practice” is to lock everything down; use fine grained access control to only grant access to the when needed, by those who need access. Even with metadata removed, allowing public access to the images could be risky; if someone scrapes the images and then runs recognition on them, it could reveal other information about your users if combined with other data sources.

Comment: Well, the software I'm currently building is not being built for a client, so getting to know what the user expects is a more difficult. The profile pictures that I store serve the same purpose as the ones on Stack Overflow. I was more inclined to store them publicly, since SO and other big services do this as well.

Comment: Fair. Even with that context, my comment remains the same: err on the side of caution. An image of a person is considered PII (personally identifiable information) in many jurisdictions and in many contexts… You should definitely seek qualified legal advice on these sorts of subjects.